# How to apt-update when apt is not accepting the repository?

Tags: debian

I want to do `apt-get` update on my debian machine. However, I am getting this.

> Get:4 http://deb.torproject.org squeeze Release [2,951 B]
>   Err http://deb.torproject.org squeeze Release  (other repositories
>   that are OK) W: A error occurred during the signature verification.
>   The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be
>   used. GPG error: http://deb.torproject.org squeeze Release: The
>   following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1346668560 KEYEXPIRED
>   1346668560 KEYEXPIRED 1346668560 KEYEXPIRED 1346668560
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/squeeze/Release
>
> W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

What should I do? I don't want to remove the torproject repository, I still use tor time from time...

Comment: I was able to install that key successfully by first switching from user privileges to root privileges with `sudo -s`, then the key installs. then remember to `exit` back to user mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note:** `apt-key` is [deprecated](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-key.8.en.html)

You could try updating the repository key. When I try to use the tor repository by adding this line to my sources.lst:

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org squeeze main
```

I get the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://deb.torproject.org squeeze InRelease: The following 
signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
NO_PUBKEY 74A941BA219EC810
```

So, the missing key is 74A941BA219EC810. To add (or update in your case) the key run:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net  74A941BA219EC810
```

You should now be able to run `apt-get update with no errors.

Comment: This worked for me: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 74A941BA219EC810`

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** `apt-key` is [deprecated](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-key.8.en.html)

To find any expired repository keys and their IDs, use `apt-key` as follows:

```
apt-key list --keyid-format short | fgrep expired
```

You will get a result similar to the following:

```
pub   4096R/BE1DB1F1 2011-03-29 [expired: 2014-03-28]
```

The key ID is the bit after the `/` i.e. `BE1DB1F1` in this case.

To update the key, as terdon points out, run

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net BE1DB1F1
```

Comment: How to do this if the output now is `pub   rsa2048 2009-09-04 [SC] [expires: 2022-08-05]
      A3C4 F0F9 79CA A22C DBA8  F512 EE8C BC9E 886D DD89`?

Comment: Use `--keyid-format short`. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove the repository but only disable it. This won't remove tor, just stop it from being updated.

In any case there's a problem with the repository's signature. You might try to remove the repository and add it again. It might solve the problem.